# How to allow different from USD currency in activemerchant gem?

Tags: paypal, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

I can not make a `purchase` via `activemerchant`if my currency is not 'USD'
Here's error text message from `response.message`:
`The transaction currency specified must be the same as previously specified.`

Here's purchase setup:

```
response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(product.price,       
      :currency          => product.currency.upcase, # it's 'EUR'
      :items             => [{name: product.name, quantity: 1, amount: product.price, description: product.description}],
      :ip                => request.remote_ip,
      :return_url        => paypal_checkout_url,
      :cancel_return_url => paypal_checkout_url
)
```

And here's purchase itself:

```
def purchase
  response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(product.price, express_purchase_options)
end

def express_purchase_options
{
  :ip => ip_address,
  :token => express_token,
  :payer_id => express_payer_id
}
end
```

Maybe I should specify currency in `express_purchase_options` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the currency specified needs to be the same in all calls throughout the flow.  It looks like this must be using Express Checkout..??  You just need to make sure the SetExpressCheckout request and the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request are using the same currency code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using PayPal ExpressCheckout

Comment: Same problem with me first i request **SetExpressCheckout** with **AUD**  and again next time **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** with **AUD** but getting this error.

Comment: Need to see samples of your requests to confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this gem in one of my projects with 'EUR' currency.

My configuration is as follows:

```
# config/application.rb
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.default_currency = 'EUR'
end
```

And that's it. No need to configure anything else.

Comment: And remember to reload the rails server after this change.